# How to bind datagridview's data source property to combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to bind list of objects as a data source for data grid, on of the columns should be a combobox where selected value of the combobox should be value in the filed related in my object.

This is how I set the datasource of gridview :

```
var s = new BindingSource();
s.DataSource = dbc.GetResults();
dataGridView.DataSource = s;
```

dbc.GetResults(id) will return List and myClass which is

```
Class myClass
{
 int productID{ set; get; }
 int price{ set; get; }
}
```

And then I am initialling data grid view like this :

```
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dgvc.HeaderText = "Products";
dgvc.DataSource = dbc.GetAllProducts();
dgvc.DisplayMember = "Name";
dgvc.ValueMember = "ID";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvc);
dataGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "productID";
```

and dbc.GetAllProducts() returns list and :

```
Class Products
{
 int ID;
 string Name; 
}
```

Here I expect that data grids get productID from myClass and pass it to combobox on each row, then the combo box gets the productID matches it with the ID in products column and then shows the Name property of it.

when I run this I get the error that DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Comment: Did you look at your debugger and check the values of everything?

Comment: @MethodMan at the beginning of my question, dataGridView.DataSource = s;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a dictionary to bind your property to your combo :

```
private Dictionary<int, string> cbProductVals= new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Populate your dictionary with product objects and bind it on your grid column.

In your datagrid AutoGeneratingColumn event :

```
if (e.PropertyName == "productID")
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    e.Column = cb;
    cb.ItemsSource = cbProductVals;
    cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    cb.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
    cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("productID");
    e.Column.Header = "product price";
}
```